# Bash scripts that reads hostnames.txt and outputs their IPs to screen or another txt file

Tags: bash

`host unix.stackexchange.com` at the command line, gives you the following results:

```
unix.stackexchange.com has address 198.252.206.140
```

I would like to use this command in a bash script that will read hostname.txt which has multiple hostnames listed like so:

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
```

I would then like it to either output results to screen or another txt file.

Comment: A simple `while` loop can do that, did you try writing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple code snippet that does what you ask for:

```
cat hostname.txt | while read line
do
    host $line | grep ' address '
done >output.txt
```

Remove the `grep` filter if you want *all* the output, it's just there to match what you requested in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to bash and was not familiar with the 'while' statement.  This worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet that saved as a script and made executable will produce the output you requested.  I added piping `|` the output through `grep` to filter out other output from `host` that can occur.

```
cat hostname.txt | while read line; do
    x="$(host "$line")"
    echo "$x" | grep 'address'
done
```

Say the `hostname.txt` file contains:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
stackoverflow.com
```

The output as written will be:

```
google.com has address 216.58.219.142
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4008:808::200e
yahoo.com has address 98.138.253.109
yahoo.com has address 206.190.36.45
yahoo.com has address 98.139.183.24
stackoverflow.com has address 198.252.206.140
```

Without piping `|` the output through `grep` it's:

```
google.com has address 216.58.219.142
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4008:808::200e
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
yahoo.com has address 206.190.36.45
yahoo.com has address 98.139.183.24
yahoo.com has address 98.138.253.109
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
stackoverflow.com has address 198.252.206.140
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

When executing the script you can redirect the output by e.g.:

```
scriptname > output.txt
```

You can change `cat hostname.txt` to `cat $@` to then use the script, e.g:

```
scriptname hostname.txt
```

Or:

```
scriptname hostname.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I used the script given by first user, but this would very well have worked also.